# Custom column to sum values from second table with conditional statement

Tags: powerquery, m

I have two tables, the first table has a list of invoice numbers and the second table has a list of products associated with each invoice.  I want to sum the total cost of the products for each invoice and include it in the first table using Excel Power Query.

**Table 1**
**[InvoiceNumbers] [OtherData]**

**Table 2**
**[Product] [Amount] [InvoiceNumber]**

List.Sum() seems to be the function I need to use, but I cannot filter table 2 by invoice number using this function

Table.SelectRows() can be used to select the second table, and filter it to a specific set of rows, but I cannot seem to filter the rows of Table 2 using a column from Table 1.

I have also looked into Grouping and joining the table, but because of other factors I have left out, this is not going to work.

The full query Im working with looks like this.

```
List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [InvoiceNumber] = [InvoiceNumber])[Amount])
```

This just returns the sum of all the rows because [InvoiceNumber] is equal to itself.

How can I reference the Invoice Number of the row in Table 1 to use it as a condition in the Table.SelectRows() function?  Or is there a better way to get the data sum the from Table 2?

**Table 1 Final**
**[InvoiceNumber] [OtherData] [SumOfAmounts]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a restriction to group the invoice details table, you could just reference it, and group the reference

1) Reference the table:
[image]

2) Group the referenced table:

[image]

3) Then merge the reference table and expand the total column

[image]

If this helps please remember to mark the answer

Comment: I ended up having to change the table and use this method.